# Does anyone know how I can create a 8x8 grid on python?

Tags: python, character-encoding, functional-programming

I need some help creating the code, I have been unable to create it after a long period of attempts and require some help. I am using Python 3.3.3 and 3.3.6. Any responses would be much appreciated.

I have come up with this 3x3 grid so far, but can't upscale it.

```
def printGrid():
    print('┌─┬─┬─┐' '\n'
        '│' + intToText(boxes[0][0]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[1][0]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[2][0]) + '│' '\n'
        '├─┼─┼─┤' '\n'
        '│' + intToText(boxes[0][1]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[1][1]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[2][1]) + '│' '\n'
        '├─┼─┼─┤' '\n'
        '│' + intToText(boxes[0][2]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[1][2]) + '│' + intToText(boxes[2][2]) + '│' '\n'
        '└─┴─┴─┘')
```

Comment: Please read the [How to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us some code, where you are having trouble exactly. Include any error messages as well.

Comment: you can use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) ... [example](http://screencloud.net/v/snyN)

Comment: *"but cant upscale it"* - because you've written it in a profoundly un-scalable way. For one thing, `boxes` appears to be nested the "wrong" (at least, unintuitive) way around (it would be easier if the *second* index incremented along each row, not the first).

Comment: are you sure about your tags you're using? I think you should remove character-encoding and functional-programming. Or do you have problems e.g. with encoding? And also the question is how to do an 8x8 grid. Maybe formulate this one more general.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- You need a top line, a "middle" line and a bottom line in the correct width. You can construct them by concatenating (for the top line) `"┌"` + n-1 times `"─┬"` + `"─┐"`.
- You should probably look for the largest number in `boxes` first - as constructed now, the boxes are only large enough for single digits. You might need to make them wider and use print formatting to ensure that each box will be filled to the same width.
- Then you can iterate `for box in boxes` and do `"|".join(int_to_text(item) for item in box)` to join their contents. Don't forget the leading and trailing `"|"`.